# Drupal 7 making multiple sleep connections

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am using latest Drupal7 version and using very high configuration with 16MB RAM database, multiple application server same database but facing issue of too many connections which lead to outage. Database showing NULL sleep connections.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+---+------+------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------+
| Id| User | Host       | db      | Command | Time | State | Info |
+---+------+------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------+
| 3 | user | 10.11.37.01| drupal7 | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL |
| 4 | user | 10.11.37.02| drupal7 | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL |
| 5 | user | 10.11.37.02| drupal7 | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL |
| 6 | user | 10.11.37.03| drupal7 | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL |
| 7 | user | 10.11.37.03| drupal7 | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL |
| 8 | user | 10.11.37.04| drupal7 | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL |
+------+-----------+---------------------+-------------------+----+
```

After 400 max_connection it showing outage as I defined the max_connection=400. This is ideal configuration. What should I do to resolve this.